# send response to local file

Tags: java, html, xmlhttprequest

I've got simple `html` page with one button

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function sender() {
            var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
            oReq.open('GET', 'http://localhost:8888?param2=value2', true);
            oReq.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (oReq.readyState == 4) {
                    if (oReq.status == 200) {
                        alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
                    }
                    if (oReq.status == 404) {
                        alert("404040404!");
                    }
                }
            };
            oReq.send();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="click" onclick="sender();">Send</button>
</body>
</html>
```

And I've got simple http server written on java which does nothing except reading incoming requests and showing it console.

But how to send response to my file from server? For example my file is located there

```
file:///C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/development/test.html
```

And request looks like this

```
GET /?param2=value2 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8888
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en,ru-ru;q=0.8,ru;q=0.5,en-us;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Origin: null
Connection: keep-alive

Header parsing result: param2=value2
```

Where and how send response?

Server is reading header like this

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            sock.getInputStream()));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    while (true) {
        line = reader.readLine();
        if (line == null || line.isEmpty())
            break;
        sb.append(line + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    }
    return sb.toString();
```

Comment: I'm confused. You want to write the response to a file? It's just an HTTP server so load the server in a browser with the request you used and save the page. I mean to say, navigate to http://localhost:8888?param2=value2 in your browser and save the page.

Comment: If you wish to save file to disk from javascript, then it is not possible.

Comment: Erm...Oh! It's me who was confused! I thought I can't send response if file has `file:///` instead of some web url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you're already getting the response, and if the request is OK the response is displayed in a Javascript alert. Just do any manipulation you need to replace this alert with an actual display in your HTML page.

```
oReq.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (oReq.readyState == 4) {
                    if (oReq.status == 200) {
                        //This is where you should put the code (or function call) when everything went ok
                    }
                    if (oReq.status == 404) {
                        //this is when you got a 404 error
                    }
                }
            };
```

If you wish to save it to a file on the client machine, then you should send back a filestream  from your server-side code than can then be saved by the client (like any file download), but as far as I know, you can't do it in full AJAX and you will need a plain http request to do it. Please note also that you miss a big part of error handling in your AJAX code... there are many ways a request could fail other than a 404 error, and actually as you're the one setting up all this the 404 error is maybe the least probable to happen.

Comment: Well it's actually some specific http server on localhost...it's like application with `html` code runs as long as server is not. something like this....